# How to avoid password validation, if it is generated and consists in params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a user model with generate_password action.
When i create a new user, the password is generated automatically and inserted into params like:

```
"user_params"=>
  {"name"=>"name",
   "surname"=>"secname",
   "password"=>"j6WW9kj6"}
```

, so user don't need to feel a password field. And as I have a password present validation, rails throw a validation error when I attempt to create new user.

Answer (score 0):

With my understanding, I can say that you are trying to generate a password when the user is created for the first time.

I think for this problem you can use `before_create` in `User` model.

`before_create :generate_password`

Answer (score 0):

The answer is pretty simple. I just should run password_generate method in users_controller, and ActiveRecord does all for me:

```
@user = User.new user_params
@user.password = @user.generate_password
```

Thanks.